# Why the seconds value in R is changed from the Source data for some rows using read_excel function in R - 3.1.2, one column is in Date format?

Tags: r

I am trying to import a .xlsx file using read_excel function in R in which one column is in Date format(2019-09-30 14:50:45.000) from source excel file. After importing, in the dataset, Second value of the Date column varied that is (2019-09-30 14:50:44).

I wonder why the value is changed by (-1 second) for all exceptional rows. Is there any date format I should follow while importing in R from excel?

data <- read_excel("Z:\Documents\Results\DB.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")

I expect the same Date value from excel after importing in R since the folder name i am searching is having the Date as part of it including Seconds dynamically.

Thanks in Advance!!

In my case, consider an excel with following columns and data:

**SNO**  **ID**      **Date**        **Test**
1.         503    1/9/2019 1:34:02 PM     A
2.         504    7/9/2019 5:34:02 PM     C
3.         505    3/9/2019 11:44:05 PM    B
4.         506    18/10/2019 11:07:26 AM  A

data <- read_excel("Z:\Documents\Results\DB.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")

Expected Result is

**SNO**  **ID**      **Date**         **Test**
1.        503    1-9-2019 1:34:02 PM     A
2.        504    7-9-2019 5:34:00 PM     C
3.        505    3-9-2019 11:44:05 PM    B
4.        506    18-10-2019 11:07:26 AM  A

The output coming is

**SNO**  **ID**      **Date**            **Test**
1.         503    1-9-2019 1:34:02 PM         A
2.         504    **7-9-2019 5:33:59 PM**     C
3.         505    **3-9-2019 11:44:04 PM**    B
4.         506    18-10-2019 11:07:26 AM      A

Even i tried using 
data <- read.xlsx("Z:\Documents\Results\DB.xlsx",sheet = "Sheet1", detectDates = FALSE)

which was giving the column as numeric and i used the following code to convert it manually to Date:
data$Date<- convertToDateTime(data$Date)

data$Date <- strptime(data$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "Asia/Singapore")

But still i am not getting the expected results:(

Comment: Please reformat your title. RStudio is currently on 1.2.x. Perhaps you meant R? Also include some reproducible data with which people can test possible solutions and/or verify the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Nelson ..I tried to create a model dataset as well..